# PyOpenGL isn't working

Tags: python-2.7, pyopengl

I installed PyOpenGl so I could use it with Python 2.7 but whenever I try to run an example from the examples folder an error appears. How can I run PyOpenGl correctly?

Comment: please [edit] your question and give the full text of the error message